# rsa securid and ipad application integration

Tags: ipad, integration, rsa, securid

I would like to integrate RSA SecurID TFA (Two-Factor-Authentication) in the iPAD application. Along with the username/password the user will also prompted for the SecurID token to access the application.

How do I integrate the iPAD on the application with the RSA Authentication Manager for the validation of the SecurID token? What are the interfaces exposed by RSA Authentication Manager?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 2):

1. The easiest answer is probably RADIUS. The RSA Authentication Manager has an embedded 802.1x-compliant RADIUS server, powered by Juniper Steel Belted Radius. The RSA Radius server supports PAP and EAP authentication protocols including POTP, TTLS, PEAP, and EAP15.
2. Apple's "iPad for Business Security Overview" tells us that the iPad provides native support for both the RSA SecurID and the CryptoCard hand-held authenticators for enterprise networks which require two-factore authentication tokens for VPN access. See: http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/pdf/iPad_Security_Overview.pdf
3. RSA, where I am a sometimes consultant, also offers the One-Time Password Secifications (OTPS) as guidelines for how to integrate SecurID authentication into a wide variety of systems, protocols, and devices. See the resources offered by RSA Labs on RSA.com.
4. RSA also offers a SDK and a freely-downloadable software app for anyone who wants to use their iPad (iOS 3.2 or later) as host to a software token-emulation app. This turns the iPad itself into a hand-held authenticator which generates SecurID 60-second one-time passwords. See: http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=3651

Hope this helps.

Suerte,

```
 _Vin
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about the API for SecurID, but Scorpion Software has an open API for their AuthAnvil two-factor authentication system that is completely supported using web services. We integrated it in our PHP website, in our ordeing system using Javascript and hooked it into our internal database app (winforms) using C#. Always in less than 5 lines of code. All in an afternoon.

You can check them out at [www.scorpionsoft.com](http://www.scorpionsoft.com).